# difference between Spring Boot's dependency-management Gradle plugin and Gradle's dependencyResolutionManagement / versionCatalogs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

We have a relatively large Java project (~20 modules) building with Gradle that we have been upgrading over the past few months to follow better practices.
One of the main issue we have is around *dependency management*. For very obvious reason, we need to keep our dependencies as up-to-date as we can.
We recently consolidated our projects by more judiciously using `allprojects` and `subprojects` blocks.

We are now focusing on actually making maintaining dependencies easier. We first started using Gradle's newer `dependencyResolutionManagement` ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs)) and that seems like a great option. We already started consolidating some external dependencies similar to:

```
// settings.gradle
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            version('aws', '2.20.29')
            library('aws-athena', 'software.amazon.awssdk', 'athena').versionRef('aws')
            library('aws-auth', 'software.amazon.awssdk', 'auth').versionRef('aws')
            library('aws-bom', 'software.amazon.awssdk', 'bom').versionRef('aws')
            library('aws-ssm', 'software.amazon.awssdk', 'ssm').versionRef('aws')
            library('aws-sqs', 'software.amazon.awssdk', 'sqs').versionRef('aws')

            version('jackson', '2.15.2')
            library('jackson-core', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', 'jackson-core').versionRef('jackson')
            library('jackson-databind', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', 'jackson-databind').versionRef('jackson')
            library('jackson-csv', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', 'jackson-dataformat-csv').versionRef('jackson')
            library('jackson-jdk8', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', 'jackson-datatype-jdk8').versionRef('jackson')
            library('jackson-jsr310', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', 'jackson-datatype-jsr310').versionRef('jackson')

            version('junit', '5.9.1')
            library('junit-bom', 'org.junit', 'junit-bom').versionRef('junit')
            library('junit-jupiter', 'org.junit.jupiter', 'junit-jupiter').versionRef('junit')

        }
    }
}
```

But, our project is heavily leveraging Spring Boot. All our artifacts are Spring Boot apps, services, etc. So, we use the `io.spring.dependency-management` [Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/).

I am trying to figure if both of them do the same thing? or does the Spring Boot plugin only deal with dependencies that are brought via Spring Boot's starter projects like `spring-boot-starter-web`?